# How does tensorflow ignore undefined flags

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, gunicorn

I'm wrapping my tensorflow model in a simple `flask` server and I'm adding `gunicorn` wsgi for the `flask` server. When I ran the gunicorn and tried to send a request to call my train function that has been import to the flask server, I got an error from command line arguments parsing:

> absl.flags._exceptions.UnrecognizedFlagError: Unknown command line
>   flag 'b'

I know this flags is passed when gunicorn bind the address arguments, because I have no flags named as 'b' for tensorflow. So my question is how does tensorflow ignore these undefined flags that the `tf.app.run()` function will not complain?

FYI, Here is my server structure:

**wsgi.py:**

```
from simple_server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**simple_server.py:**

```
from my_tf_model import my_train

@app.route('/call_train', methods=['POST'])
def call_train():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        training_data = request.json
        my_train(training_data, param2)  
        return('Trained!')
```

**my_tf_model.py:**

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('model_version',1, 'version number of the model.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('work_dir', '', 'Working directory.')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def my_train(param1, param2):
    # Train Algorithm
    export_path_base = FlAGS.work_dir
    # Exporting model code

def main(argv):

    my_train(param1, param2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

**Update:**

I'm using `tensorflow 1.5.x` and `python 3.6.0`, the command that I used for gunicorn is:

`gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -t 30 wsgi:app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by defining these flags in tensorflow model: `my_tf_model.py`.

```
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('bind', '', 'Server address')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('timeout', 30, 'Server timeout')
```

And then changed my gunicorn command line to use double dash style command line:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 30 wsgi:app
```

But I think there should be some other way rather than this hack to resolve the globally-used flags.

Comment: same problem here, this fixed my error, (and it should be --timeout). Btw did you find any other way to fix this?

Comment: @Thaiseer Nope, I haven't found any. I've read the source code of handling these flags. However, I think they will not ignore these undefined global flags. My solution is just a work around, it's a dirty change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using gunicorn default config file: `gunicorn.conf.py`

You can create a config file named `gunicorn.conf.py`:

```py
bind = 0.0.0.0:5000
timeout = 30
```

FYI: [Settings - Gunicorn documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html)

`gunicorn_conf.py` is the default config file name defined in function `gunicorn.config.get_default_config_file`, so now you can start your service by command `gunicorn wsgi:app`.

Now tensorflow knows nothing about gunicorn config.

Notice: this default config name is not mentioned in gunicorn documentation, it's not sure whether this config file name remains unchanged in future version.